# How do I fix sentry error 403 on react.js?

Tags: reactjs, sentryreact

I just created my-React-app and after doing npm run start I get the following error:

```
POST https://o104379.ingest.sentry.io/api/5495040/envelope/?sentry_key=31f33ef1a1a74d32a00749c3718b640d&sentry_version=7 403
```

After I did npm `install --save @sentry/react @sentry/tracing` to try to fix it but still is not working. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: It seems we need to set a token for that, but I don't know how...

Comment: I have exactly the same error but with angular. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Nope, I didn't manage to fix it

Answer (score 5):

If you are not using sentry on your project, there is high chance that browser extension is causing it.

After a bit of investigation in my devtools, I found out that in my case it was Revolut browser extension.

There are several options you can do:

1. remove extension - I removed it, since I used it maybe once or twice
2. try to update it to newer version, if available
3. write to extension devs and report a bug